# Typing "eats" text on the right

Tags: key-bindings, overwrite

Sometimes key binding changes unexpectedly such that if I position the cursor next to the first occurence of 'm'

```
lorem ipsum
```

and type 'xxxx', I get

```
loremxxxxum
```

instead of:

```
loremxxxx ipsum
```

Also, typing backspace replaced each character by a blank rather than deleting it.

If I quit and re-open the fame file, backspace works as expected. What causes this problem and how to fix it during an Emacs session?

This is using GNU Emacs 26.3 (GUI)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've accidentally turn on `overwrite-mode`, probably by accidentally hitting the `<insert>` key (typically labeled <kbd>Insert</kbd> on your keyboard).

When `overwrite-mode` is enabled, text you type replaces existing text.

As for how to "fix it": just hit the `<insert>` key again: it's a toggle key.

(As [@db48x](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/9982) mentioned in his answer, you can turn on `view-lossage` to see which keys and mouse actions you've recently used. That will no doubt show you that you used key `<insert>`.)

Comment: If you don't know what the `<insert>` key is, toggle `M-x overwrite-mode` (man 5.21).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `M-x view-lossage` to review the last few hundred keystrokes.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you never want `overwrite-mode`, you can put this in your init file:

```
(put 'overwrite-mode 'disabled t)
```